# Kubernetes Nginx ingress returns http errors 400 with uri containing %3C and %3E

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, webapi, http-status-code-400

I deployed via Helm a webapi on a Kubernetes cluster hosted on Azure.
The webapi is accessible via the ingress Nginx nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io and is functional because most of the requests are ok and returns good responses.
However, I encountered problems because the ingress returns http errors with status 400 for specific requests and doesn't reach the webapi.
The ingress returns these http errors 400 on specific requests because of special characters "<" and ">" which are encoded.

=> "%3C" for "<"

=> "%3E" for ">"

For example, the request looks like "https://example.com/api/example/id/endDate/%3E/2023-08-14T09:06:55.865Z".

I didn't found the solution to make Nginx ingress accept these special characters although the request is well-formatted and is functional with a simple Nginx.

Has anyone an idea or a solution to make the Nginx ingress accept requests and call the webapi ?

Thanks by advance for your time and your responses :D.

Ben

If I remove these two strings from the request, the ingress doesn't return a http error 400 anymore, that is a proof of this behaviour.

I tried adding ingress annotations but no ones solved the problem.

If I deploy the webapi on a simple Nginx reverse-proxy, the request returns good responses.

I found a solution which consists in encoding two times before calling the webapi and decoding two times from the webapi but I think it's a bad solution on long term.

Comment: This might help: [How do I redirect a URL with special (%C2%A0) characters in Nginx](https://serverfault.com/a/1088799/111021)